# PHP Output Query

Tags: php

Im new to the forum but hope someone can give me a hand im struggling..

my code is below, i am exporting to a csv file from the zen cart database

```
$products_cost =
    "select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_quantity, ".
      "p.products_cost, (p.products_quantity*p.products_cost) AS products_total_cost, ".
      "p.products_type ".
    "from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ".
    "where p.products_id = pd.products_id and pd.language_id='" . $_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' ".
    "order by (p.products_cost) DESC, p.products_cost desc, pd.products_name";

  $products_stock = $db->Execute($products_cost);

//Start Of Output for Stock File

$output = array();      
$output["tx_type"]='ST';        
$output["Stock_Code"]= $products_stock->fields['products_id'];
$output["Qty"]= $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];
$output["Description"]= $products_stock->fields['products_name'];
$output["CostPriceEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'];
$output["TotalCostEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'] * $products_stock->fields['products_quantity']; 

zen_sages_fwrite($output);

$stimer = microtime_float();
```

When running the code i get an output like below, but instead of showing each product from the database it is showing the same one ??

```
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
ST,1149,10,350gsm A6 Glossy Postcards,290.0000,2900
```

I have tried adding `$products_stock->MoveNext();`

But dosent seam to have any affect,

Thanking you all in advance

Russell

My Code Now looks like

//Start Of Output for Stock File

```
$output = array();  while (!$products_stock->EOF) {


$output["tx_type"]='ST';


$output["Stock_Code"]= $products_stock->fields['products_id'];


$output["Qty"]= $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];


$output["Description"]= $products_stock->fields['products_name'];


$output["CostPriceEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'];


$output["TotalCostEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'] * $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];
```

$products_stock->MoveNext;

```
}
```

zen_sages_fwrite($output);

$stimer = microtime_float();

Comment: Are you using PDO?  It's only doing one as you are only fetching one row.  Depending on the resource type `$products_stock` is, you'll want to create a loop that will run through each row for you, writing as you go (or saving it to write all at once). Also, as a side note, you have calculated the total cost in your query, why calculate again in PHP rather than use the field from the DB?

Comment: HI jon, thank you for your reply, im not sure what PDO is ? how would one create this loop ? my experiance is quite limited.yes i should have and will amend thank you in advance..

Comment: At the beginning of your `$output = array()` add `while (!$products_stock->EOF) {` and close the while after your `fwrite` with a `}`, but right before that, add `$products_stock->MoveNext;`

Comment: HI Jon thanks so much for your help, i really appriciate it, i have added in but now is producing no results ??

Comment: Did it work after adding it? ^^

Comment: nope i hope i put it in the right place tho i have posted it above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting in answer form so you can get it working quicker ^^
You want something like:

```
while(!$products_sock->EOF) {
    $output = array();      
    $output["tx_type"]='ST';        
    $output["Stock_Code"]= $products_stock->fields['products_id'];
    $output["Qty"]= $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];
    $output["Description"]= $products_stock->fields['products_name'];
    $output["CostPriceEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'];
    $output["TotalCostEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'] * $products_stock->fields['products_quantity']; 

    zen_sages_fwrite($output);
    $products_stock->MoveNext();
}
```

With the code you added above, you overwrite `$output` with every loop, this will write it every loop before overwriting it.

Or try:

```
for($i=0;$i<$products_stock->rowCount();$i++) {
    $output = array();      
    $output["tx_type"]='ST';        
    $output["Stock_Code"]= $products_stock->fields['products_id'];
    $output["Qty"]= $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];
    $output["Description"]= $products_stock->fields['products_name'];
    $output["CostPriceEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'];
    $output["TotalCostEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'] * $products_stock->fields['products_quantity']; 

    zen_sages_fwrite($output);
    $products_stock->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: HI Jon,Thats sort of done it, but the loop  isnt ending after displaying all our products

Comment: What does it do when you say it doesn't end?

Comment: its as if the loops hasnt been ended.

Comment: I'm not sure why, the `!$products_sock->EOF` condition of the while loop should end it after the last row. =/

Comment: You can try a `for` loop, going from `0` to `$products_stock->RecordCount()` which should cap it.  Added example to answer. ^^

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks so much for your help, but the new code above just errors and dosent produce anything just get a white screen..

Comment: Aye.  Sorry then, I couldn't find much documentation about the Zen cart, and from what I could find, the while loop should have worked.  The for loop was more a hope. ^^

Comment: hi Jon it wouldnt have anything to do with $products_cost =
    "select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_quantity, ".
      "p.products_cost, (p.products_quantity*p.products_cost) AS products_total_cost, ".
      "p.products_type ".
    "from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ".
    "where p.products_id = pd.products_id and pd.language_id='" . $_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' ".
    "order by (p.products_cost) DESC, p.products_cost desc, pd.products_name";

  $products_stock = $db->Execute($products_cost);

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with that query that would make it do that. =/